# Australian landmarks

Tags: knowledge, geography, sports, connections-puzzle

I'm trying to make a list of prominent Australian landmarks, but I'm having real trouble with one entry. Could you help me out? Here's my list so far.

Brisbane: **Stranahan's Distillery**
Canberra: **Mob Museum**
Gold Coast: **Camelback Mountain**
Gosford: **Kerry Park**
Melbourne: ??
Newcastle: **Chelsea Market**
Perth: **Elfreth's Alley**
Sydney: **Pier 39**
Townsville: **Reunion Tower**

However, I can't wrap my head around which landmark belongs to the Melbourne spot. My shortlist of four candidates is **French Quarter**, **Grant's Farm**, **Guardian Building** and **Lenox Square**. Can you find any logic here? Why is this so difficult?

Comment: As a fellow Aussie I am pleased to see this puzzle. Had me quite confused for a while though :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, here's the thing:

> none of these are actually in Australia. Their real locations are as follows:
>
>  Stranahan's Distillery: Denver, CO
>  Mob Museum: Las Vegas, NV
>  Camelback Mountain: Phoenix, AZ
>  Kerry Park: Seattle, WA
>  Chelsea Market: New York, NY
>  Elfreth's Alley: Philadelphia, PA
>  Pier 39: San Francisco, CA
>  Reunion Tower: Dallas, TX
>
>  French Quarter: New Orleans, LA
>  Grant's Farm: St. Louis, MO
>  Guardian Building: Detroit, MI
>  Lenox Square: Atlanta, GA

This didn't make a whole lot of sense to me until I saw

> the [sports] tag. It turns out that each of the Australian cities has a sports team that has the same name as a team in the corresponding American city. For example, the [National Rugby League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Rugby_League) includes the Brisbane Broncos and the Canberra Raiders, while the [National Football League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Football_League) includes the Denver Broncos and the Las Vegas Raiders.

That means we need to find

> a team in Melbourne that shares its name with a team in one of the four American cities that are our options.

Sounds easy right? Well, here's why Jafe was having trouble:

> Melbourne is the center of gravity for the [Australian Football League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_Football_League); no fewer than nine of the AFL's teams are located in the city! Sure enough, those teams include the Saints (also the name of New Orleans' NFL team), Blues (St. Louis in the National Hockey League), Tigers (the Major League Baseball team in Detroit), and the Hawks (Atlanta's contribution to the National Basketball Association).

Therefore, the answer to which landmark should be associated with Melbourne is

> all of the above!

---

Added 13 March: here's a list of all the connections mentioned (with a bit of help from OP in comments):

> [Brisbane Broncos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brisbane_Broncos) ([NRL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Rugby_League)) = [Denver Broncos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denver_Broncos) ([NFL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Football_League))
>  [Canberra Raiders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canberra_Raiders) (NRL) = [Las Vegas Raiders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Las_Vegas_Raiders) (NFL)
>  [Gold Coast Suns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_Coast_Suns) ([AFL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_Football_League)) = [Phoenix Suns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_Suns) ([NBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Basketball_Association))
>  [Central Coast Mariners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Coast_Mariners_FC) ([A-League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-League_Men)) = [Seattle Mariners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seattle_Mariners) ([MLB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_League_Baseball))
>  [Newcastle Jets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newcastle_Jets_FC) (A-League) = [New York Jets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_Jets) (NFL)
>  [West Coast Eagles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Coast_Eagles) (AFL) = [Philadelphia Eagles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philadelphia_Eagles) (NFL)
>  [Greater Western Sydney Giants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greater_Western_Sydney_Giants) (AFL) = [San Francisco Giants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Francisco_Giants) (MLB)
>  [North Queensland Cowboys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Queensland_Cowboys) (NRL) = [Dallas Cowboys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dallas_Cowboys) (NFL)
>  [St Kilda Saints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St_Kilda_Football_Club) (AFL) = [New Orleans Saints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Orleans_Saints) (NFL)
>  [Carlton Blues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlton_Football_Club) (AFL) = [St. Louis Blues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Louis_Blues) ([NHL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Hockey_League))
>  [Richmond Tigers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richmond_Football_Club) (AFL) = [Detroit Tigers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detroit_Tigers) (MLB)
>  [Hawthorn Hawks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawthorn_Football_Club) (AFL) = [Atlanta Hawks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlanta_Hawks) (NBA)
>
>  Please get into a big argument in the comments about whether Australia or the US has better logo design.

Comment: Exactly so! For completeness, the full list is rot13(Oevfonar Oebapbf, Pnaoreen Envqref, Tbyq Pbnfg Fhaf, Prageny Pbnfg (Tbfsbeq) Znevaref, Arjpnfgyr Wrgf, Jrfg Pbnfg (Cregu) Rntyrf, Terngre Jrfgrea Flqarl Tvnagf, naq Abegu Dhrrafynaq (Gbjafivyyr) Pbjoblf. Gurfr jrer pbzovarq sebz Nhfgenyvn'f gbc yrnthrf bs Nhffvr ehyrf (NSY), ehtol yrnthr (AEY) naq fbppre (N-Yrnthr).)